# Sqlce {"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 27,Token in error = CONTAINS ]"}

Tags: c#, sql

I have a field in Plant table SeedStartMonths as nvarchar that contains 1 2 4 11.  I'm trying to SELECT * FROM Plant WHERE CONTAINS(SeedStartMonths, '11') and it giving me error.

```
    string tmp = ( (int) thisMonth ).ToString();
            using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Plant WHERE CONTAINS(SeedStartMonths, '" + tmp + "')", con))
            {
                SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        AddReaderToGardenEntityList(gardenEntities, reader);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //unable to parse datas
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL-CE does not support the `CONTAINS` predicate function. However it does support the `LIKE` operator, you must rewrite your query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Plant WHERE SeedStartMonths LIKE '%11%'
```

Comment: the problem is plant a have : 1 2 3 4 5, plant b have 11 12,  how would i write it just to only want 1.

Comment: @HieuNTrinh Try `LIKE '% 1 %'` (note the spaces), but this would require that your field value be prepended with a space character, but you can do that with SQL.